# Transfering NFT from CLI to your Nami wallet

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, nft, nami-wallet

I created an NFT on preprod via my cardano-cli but I have issues sending it to my Nami wallet. Can anyone point me to the best documentation that covers this. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is [to create a simple transaction](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/stake-pool-course/handbook/create-simple-transaction/) sending the asset to your receiving Nami wallet in form of `"$tokenamount $policyid.$tokenname"`.